# Euler's formula vs. exponential function in calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I am writing an essay about the application of Euler's formula and the exponential function in calculus.  I used each of them to solve a second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation in the form $(d^2 y)/(dx^2 )-k^2 y=F$.

Both of them, of course, simplified the process of finding a solution for the differential equation (real and complex). However using the exponential function took about 3 pages while using Euler's formula took about one page.

How do I explain why Euler's formula is a more efficient way?  and is it always more efficient to solve differential equation using Euler's formula rather than exponential function or it depends?

Comment: You means that you used exponential generating functions to solve differential equations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean euler's formula vs exponential functions?

Comment: @Masacroso I   mean I substituted e^x into the equation and then followed the method of undetermined coefficients to find a solution :)

Comment: @Triatticus I mean a comparison between the exponential function e^x and Euler's formula when solving the differential equation mentioned. A comparison in the sense of which one simplified the process of finding the solution (whether real or complex) more sufficiently :)

Comment: Do you mean by letting the right hand side equal to the real/imaginary part of a complex exponential? I guess you could use the logic that dealing with a single equation is easier than using a system of equations. Im assuming F should be a co/sinusoidal function then